# Non-admin users cannot preview/view entries when site front end is disabled (multisite)

Tags: craft3, control-panel, admin, multi-site

I am running a multisite setup on 3.6.11.2. We are attempting to generate a new site and while we work on the structure/content I have the 'Enable on the front end' setting switched off. As an admin, I can still use the 'Preview' and 'View' options just fine (url looks something like /path/?siteToken=abcd123 when viewing), and if I grant admin access to another user they can as well. However, non-admin users are unable to preview/view the pages on the disabled site. I have given them the 'access when site is off settings' as well as access to the disabled site.

Checking the apache access log, non-admin users appear to be getting the same treatment as non-users, which is a 302 that then turns into an endless chain of 302s that are hitting index.php?siteToken=abcd123.

Is there a way to allow people access to preview/view entries when sites are disabled on the front end, without giving them full admin access?